# How to jump to kernel from bootloader correctly (reboot infinite trouble)

Tags: c, embedded

I write a simple bootloader whose responsibility is to load kernel, relocate kernel to the write place and jump to kernel. But it will reboot infinite after switch to protected mode and jump to kernel. Can any one figure me out where is the wrong point, and how to correct it? Thanks!

bootsec.asm

```
            [bits 16]   
            [org 0x7C00]

            mov si, hello_string

    _print:
            mov al, [si] ;ASCII value is in register AL
            cmp al, 0x00
            jz print_ok
            mov ah, 0x0E ;Tell BIOS that we need to print one charater on screen.
            mov bh, 0x00 ;Page no.
            mov bl, 0x07 ;Text attribute 0x07 is lightgrey font on black background
            int 0x10
            inc si
            jmp _print

    print_ok:

    enable_a20:
            mov ax, 0x2401
            int 0x15

    load_next_stage:
            mov ah, 2
            mov al, 4
            mov ch, 0
            mov cl, 2
            mov dh, 0
            mov dl, 0
            ;mov es, 0
            mov bx, 0x9000
            int 0x13
            jc load_next_stage

    load_done:


            cli                                ; disable interrupts
            lgdt        [gdtr32]                      ; load GDT register with start address of Global Descriptor Table
            lidt        [idtr32]
                                        ;mov         eax, cr0 
                                        ;or          al, 1                           
                                        ;mov         cr0, eax
            mov         ax, 0x0001
            lmsw        ax                     ; set PE (Protection Enable) bit in CR0 (Control Register 0)
            jmp         0x08:gdt32enable                 ; we need a jump like this to reload the CS.

            align  8
      gdt32enable:
            [bits  32]
            mov         ax,0x0010               ; set the segment selector for data that we...
            mov         ds,ax                   ; ... set to DS
            mov         es,ax                   ; ... set to ES
            mov         fs,ax                   ; ... set to FS
            mov         gs,ax                   ; ... set to GS
            mov         ss,ax                   ; ... and set to SS
            ;mov         esp,stack32+STACKSIZE   ; and we create a stack


     ;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ; load GDT ok, end enter protected mode
     ;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            ;mov         edi,0xb8000             ; set the screen buffer location
            ;mov         ecx,80*25               ; set the nbr of attr/char pairs to write
            ;xor         eax,eax                 ; clear eax
            ;mov         ax,0x0f20               ; set the attr/char pair to write
            ;rep         stosw                   ; clear the screen

            mov         eax, load_gdt_ok
            mov         edi,0xb8000             ; go back to the first column
    print_gdt:
            mov         cl, [eax]
            cmp         cl, 0x00
            jz          print_gdt_done
            or          cx, 0x9c<<8
            mov         [edi], cx
            add         edi,2                   ; move to the next position on the screen
            inc         eax
            jmp         print_gdt

     print_gdt_done:

            ;jmp         done_move

            cld
            ;mov         eax, 0x100000
            mov         edi, 0x100000
            mov         esi, 0x9000
            mov         ecx, 512

    move_kernel:                      
            mov         eax, [esi]
            mov         [edi], eax
            add         edi, 4
            add         esi, 4
            dec         ecx
            jz          done_move
            jmp         move_kernel

    done_move:
            mov         esp, 0x200000
            ;sti
            ;jmp         $
            ;jmp         0x9000
            jmp         0x100000


     hello_string: 
            db 'Hello World from bootsec...', 0 ;HelloWorld string ending with 0
    load_gdt_ok:
            db          "Load GDT ok, and enter protected mode..................", 0

            align       8
    gdt32:
            dq          0                   ; GDT entry 0x00
            dq          0x00cf9a000000ffff  ; DGT entry 0x08
            dq          0x00cf92000000ffff  ; GDT entry 0x10
    gdt32End:

    gdtr32:                                     ; this is out initial GDTR
            dw          gdt32End-gdt32-1
            dd          gdt32
    idtr32:
            dw 0
            dd 0

    times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0
    dw 0xAA55           ;Add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

kernel.c

```
    #include <stdint.h> 

    #define __ISA_IO_base 0x0

    #define __VGA_BASE (__ISA_IO_base + 0xb8000)

    #define asm __asm__

    typedef struct init_gdt32
    {
        uint64_t dummy;
        uint64_t code;
        uint64_t data;
    }init_gdt32 __attribute__((align(8)));

    init_gdt32 init_gdt32_desc = {0,0x00cf9a000000ffff,0x00cf92000000ffff};

    void kentry()
    {
         asm volatile ("lgdt %0;"::"m"(init_gdt32_desc):);
         asm (
             "mov  $0x0010, %ax;"
             "mov %ax, %ds;"
             "mov %ax, %es;"
             "mov %ax, %fs;"
             "mov %ax, %gs;"
             "mov %ax, %ss;"
            // "mov edi, 0xB8000;"
            // "movl $500, %ecx;"
            // "movl $0x1F201F20, %eax;"
            // "rep stosd;"
            // "movl $0x00b8000, %edi;"
            // "movq 0x1F6C1F6C1F651F48, %eax;"
            // "movq %rax, (%edi);"
            // "movq $0x1F6F1F571F201F6F,  %rax;"
            // "movq %rax, 8(%edi);"
            // "movq $0x1F211F641F6C1F72, %rax;"
            // "movq %rax, 16(%edi);"
         );



         kmain();
    }

     void __writew(uint32_t addr, uint16_t val)
     {
          (*(uint16_t*) addr) = val;
     }

    int kmain()
    {
         int i = 0;
         char* lint = "----------------------->hello in kernel...";
         int offset = 80*10;
         int len = 42;
         for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
         {
             __writew(__VGA_BASE + offset + i*2, (0x2c<<8) | lint[i]);
             // __writew(__VGA_BASE + offset + i*2+1, 0x9c);
         }

         while(1);


         return 0;
     }
```

kernel.test.ld

```
    OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
    ENTRY(kentry)

    KERNEL_START = 0x100000;

    SECTIONS {

         . = 0x0 ;
         kernel_lma = . ;
         . = KERNEL_START;

         __kernel_start = . ;   
         .text ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(kernel_lma) {
                 *(.text)
         }

         .data ALIGN(8) : AT(ADDR(.data) - KERNEL_START){
                 *(.data)
         }

         .bss ALIGN(8) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - KERNEL_START){
                 *(.bss)
         }

         __kernel_end = . ;
    }
```

Makefile

```
    TARGET-BIN=kernel.bin

    LINK-SCRIPT=kernel.test.ld

    AS=nasm
    CC=gcc
    LD=ld
    CFLAGS=-ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -z max-page-size=0x1000
    LD-SCRIPT=-T $(LINK-SCRIPT)
    OBJCOPY=objcopy
    OBJS = kernel.o

    .PHONY: build
    build: $(TARGET-BIN)

    $(TARGET-BIN) : $(OBJS)
        echo Linking...
        $(LD) $(LD-SCRIPT) -o $@ $(OBJS)
        $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $@ kernel.img

    %.o : %.c
        echo compiling...
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

    %.o : %.s
        echo assembling...
        $(AS) -f elf64 $< -o $@

     disk:
        cat boot.o kernel.img > OSImage
        dd if=./OSImage of=./osdisk.img

     boot:
        nasm bootsec.asm -o boot.o

    .PHONY: clean
    clean:
         echo Cleaning...
         rm -fr *.o *.bin *.img
```

Answer (score 0):

If `kmain()` is run then please check the WDT and disable it if enabled.